# .htaccess not working through internetters

Tags: file, .htaccess

iam trying to setup the .htaccess file to rewrite url's so file extensions such as .php and .html are removed, at the moment only the 404 error page works on the .htaccess

an example of one of the urls iam trying to change is: http://www.thinkbrainstormers.co.uk/clients.php

iam trying to change it to http://www.thinkbrainstormers.co.uk/clients

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

is the .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

You're going backwards: you don't remove extensions with rewrite conditions, you define paths that will go to files that have extensions. These lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

...are basically saying "if a file request comes in with a .php extension, call it with a .php extension." What you need to do is define path structures, and have those structures map to the php files you want to use. Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^episode/([0-9]+)?$ episode.php?eid=$1 [L]
```

...which will take `url.com/episode/5` and map it to `episode.php?eid=5`